# Filtering Parents by Children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm doing a simple blog application - There are posts, which have many tags through a posts_tags table (my models are below).  What I have implemented is if a user clicks a tag, it will show just the posts with that tag.  What I want is for the user to them be able to select another tag, and it will filter to only the posts that have both of those tags, then a third, then a fourth, etc.  I'm having difficulty making the active record query - especially dynamically.  The closest I've gotten is listed below - however its in pure SQL and I would like to at least have it in ActiveRecord Rubyland syntax even with the complexity it contains.

Also, the "having count 2" does not work, its saying that "count" does not exist and even if I assign it a name. However, it is outputting in my table (the idea behind count is that if it contains a number that is as much as how many tags we are searching for, then theoretically/ideally it has all the tags)

My current test SQL query

```
select posts_tags.post_id,count(*) from posts_tags where tag_id=1 or tag_id=3 group by post_id ### having count=2
```

The output from the test SQL (I know it doesnt contain much but just with some simple seed data).

```
 post_id | count 
---------+-------
       1 |     2
       2 |     1
```

My Models:
/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts_tags
    has_many :tags, :through => :posts_tags
end
```

/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts_tags
    has_many :posts, :through => :posts_tags
end
```

/poststag.rb

```
class PostsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: [1, 3]}).select("posts.id, count(*)").group("posts.id").having("count(*) > 2")
```

Comment: This was magical.  I will be spending quite a while going over this!  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I think "count = 2" is not correct. It should be "count(*) = 2". Your query then will be

```
select post_id,count(post_id) 
from posts_tags 
where tag_id = 1 or tag_id = 3 
group by post_id 
having count(post_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to stay away from writing raw sql when using rails. Active Record has great helper methods to make your sql more readable and maintainable.

If you only have a few tags you can create scopes for each of them (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Since people are clicking on tags one at a time you could just query for each tag and then use the `&` operator on the arrays. Because you have already requested the exact same set of data from the database the query results should be cached meaning you are only hitting the db for the newest query.